# Not enough permissions to access: GET-owners /shares problem

Tags: linkedin-api

I created a LinkedIn developer app that I want to use for retrieving my company's shared posts. I generated an access token of an admin of that page and tested it with a get request to /me - everything works fine.

Now I'm trying to make a request to [https://api.linkedin.com/v2/shares?q=owners&owners=urn:li:company:{id}](https://api.linkedin.com/v2/shares?q=owners&owners=urn:li:company:%7Bid%7D) and I get **Not enough permissions to access: GET-owners /shares**.
On the app I have these permissions:

- r_organization_social
- r_1st_connections_size
- r_ads_reporting
- rw_organization_admin
- r_liteprofile
- r_ads
- rw_ads
- w_member_social
- w_organization_social

What permissions am I missing? I can't apply for any more permissions as there are no options in /auth page and I have added all the products I can (Share on LinkedIn, Sign In with LinkedIn and Marketing Developer Platform).
Also, for `owners=urn:li:company:{id}` I'm not using a numeric company id, but rather a slug, does that change anything?

EDIT: I got the company numberic ID and it still doesn't work